# Why is $\sum_{t=1}^n \exp \{ -t \Delta^2\} \geq \frac{1}{\Delta^2}$?

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

I am reading a paper about lower bounds for bandit problems (https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.1611). In Theorem 5, they prove a lower bound with an example problem with two arms. In the proof, I see the following step and I wonder where it comes from.

$\sum_{t=1}^n \exp \{ -t \Delta^2\} \geq \frac{1}{\Delta^2}$

I've tried to derive it from

- a Taylor expansion,
- Jensen's inequality,
- summing to infinity,

but I don't see it.

Thanks!

Comment: Since $n=\Delta=1$ is a counterexample, you'll have to say how the context constrains $n,\,\Delta$.

Comment: From a typo, I guess. The opposite inequality is true.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Oh, dear! It comes at the end of a chain of $\ge$s at the bottom of page 8, so a $\le$ is unhelpful.

Comment: I've alerted the paper's authors of this discrepancy, though someone else probably told them 7 years ago. It's been cited [77 times](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?cites=7068990235792969863&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en), but I don't know how many such citations already brought it up.

Comment: Note that @VianneyPerchet is one of the paper's authors.

Answer (score 5):

It is the other way aroud:
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{t = 1}^n {\exp ( - t\Delta ^2 )} & \le \sum\limits_{t = 1}^n {\int_{t - 1}^t {\exp ( - s\Delta ^2 )ds} } \\ & = \int_0^n {\exp ( - s\Delta ^2 )ds}  \le \int_0^{ + \infty } {\exp ( - s\Delta ^2 )ds}  = \frac{1}{{\Delta ^2 }}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

This inequality is indeed obviously incorrect... there are several typos in the statement (and the proof) of Theorem 5. First thing first, it can only be true for $n \geq 1/\Delta^2$ (for smaller $n$, the regret is upper-bounded by $n\Delta$ which is itself smaller than $1/\Delta$). Also, the sum should be from $0$ up to $t-1$ (instead from $1$ up to $t$ as we wrote).

With standard computations, you then get  that regret is bigger than $\frac{1-e^{-1}}{4\Delta}$ and even bigger than   $\frac{1}{4\Delta}$ asymptotically with $n$ (as it goes to infinity).

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

I still don't understand how to obtain $(1-e^{-1}) / (4 \Delta)$, could you maybe spell that out for me?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum\limits_{t = 1}^n {\exp ( - t\Delta ^2 )}<\sum\limits_{t = 1}^\infty {\exp ( - t\Delta ^2 )}=\sum\limits_{t = 1}^\infty {[\exp ( - \Delta ^2 )]^t}=\frac{\exp(-\Delta^2)}{1-\exp(-\Delta^2)}=\frac1{\exp\Delta^2-1}\\ <\frac1{\Delta^2}.$$